# How to unwrap url.Error returned from http.Client?

Tags: go

I'm using `net.http.client`

After sending the request with

```golang
resp, err := Client.Do(req)
```

I'm getting the error I want to work with.

`err.Error()` returns an error as string. But I need to work with error as an object. I found the method `Unwrap()` that seems to be returning an `url.Error` object, but I'm getting `err.Unwrap undefined (type error has no field or method Unwrap)`

Sorry for dumb question, I'm totally new to golang.

Comment: what about only `err`?

Comment: @IvanAracki, `err` has no fields `Op`, `Url` and `Err` defined in `url.Error`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation, any error returned from `Client.Do` will be `*url.Error`, but since the method signature says `(*Response, error)`, you will have to convert it explicitly before use:

```
urlErr := err.(*url.Error)
if urlErr.Timeout() {
    // ..
}
```