# Access the Timeout() method from a *urlError in net/http package

Tags: go

I access a web page using Client.Get(url) function.

```
timeout := time.Duration(wgetTimeout) * time.Second
client := http.Client{Timeout: timeout}

// Get page and check for error (timeout, http ...)
res, err := client.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
defer res.Body.Close()
```

The [Client.Get() function doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get) says that:

> Any returned error will be of type *url.Error. The url.Error value's Timeout method will report true if the request timed out.

How can I access the url.Error methods like the bool Timeout() ?

The solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150236/how-to-unwrap-url-error-returned-from-http-client) requires the Client.Do() function to be used.

Comment: The linked answer does apply to Client.Get. The problem is that `url` is a string variable in your code, not the package net/url. Rename the variable and import net/url to the file.

Comment: @MuffinTop that was it. Nice catch. Worth the solution tag, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GoDoc: Type *url.Error](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Error)

```
if e, ok := err.(*url.Error); ok && e.Timeout() {
    log.Fatal("timeout is: ", e.Timeout())
} else if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: I already tried the `err.(*url.Error)` thing on the err generated by the client.Get but I get a `url.Error undefined (type string has no field or method Error)`

Comment: ... and this is excactly what puzzles me: the error generated by the `client.Get()` _is_ a `*url.Error` type of error but I can't access its documented method Timeout().

Comment: yes indeed! Nice catch. Works fine now. Thanks. Also spotted by @Muffin Top above.

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.IsTimeout](https://godoc.org/os#IsTimeout) to determine whether the error has a Timeout() method that returns true.

```
res, err := client.Get(url)
if os.IsTimeout(err) {
    // handle timeout
} else if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
```